# How to hide edge where granite countertop meets cabinet?

Tags: cabinets, countertops, granite

We're currently in the process of adding a double wall oven to our kitchen. We had to cut down the countertop to accommodate the wall oven cabinet and now we have a problem I haven't run into before. While we can easily hide the edge of the countertop touching the back using a backsplash, I have no idea how you're supposed to hide the edge of the countertop touching the cabinet?

How is this typically handled?

Thank you!

Image attached for reference: [image: Countertop meets cabinet]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is handled with caulk.  Either black or a color close to the light part of the counter, almond or tan.

I find good results if I apply the caulk.  Smooth with a finger, then wipe with a lightly wet grout sponge.  like this:  [sponge](https://hdsupplysolutions.com/p/qep-heavy-duty-grout-sponge-p131209?ef_id=Cj0KCQiA6fafBhC1ARIsAIJjL8lojd1Yxr2Lbqac48Y8Jc8BFvKpjKfGzJVq44YMg7UFvoIZJZr9pdMaAu4TEALw_wcB:G:s&cid=ppc_all_gl_pfd_Shop%7CHDSS%7CUS%7CHardware&s_kwcid=AL!10728!3!438192856735!!!g!912283916805!!10160878296!110261937988!&gclid=Cj0KCQiA6fafBhC1ARIsAIJjL8lojd1Yxr2Lbqac48Y8Jc8BFvKpjKfGzJVq44YMg7UFvoIZJZr9pdMaAu4TEALw_wcB)

Comment: Would it look bad to try to match the caulk color to the color of the cabinet?

Comment: No, in most cases, darker is better than lighter, but I have used clear caulk on my counter in the same situation and it made the joint unnoticeable without very close examination.

Comment: We just had our kitchen remodeled, and caulk is the way all these joints were handled (counter meeting a vertical side of a cabinet).  The color of the caulk matched the counters (off white quartz), not the cabinets (light wood).

Answer (score 5):

Usually a bead of caulking in your favourite available colour.

Will also seal the joint to prevent any spills from going in/under.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers are good; another other method is to glue a small run of quarter/shoe molding stained to match the cabinet. The cabinet face should be about 1/4" past the cabinet wall; you can get 1/4" molding, so it won't stick out past the cabinet face.

Looks like you have some glue or something behind the cabinet face too, so you can stain/paint that while you're at it.

Answer (score 2):

To a large extent this comes down to 1) how wide & irregular the gap is between the counter and the cabinet and 2) aesthetics/personal opinion.

Here are examples showing both approaches.  The first is from a remodel I did some 14 years ago in a previous house, and shows a backsplash used that was made from the same material (granite in this case) as the counter.

The second picture is from a recent remodel we had done where just caulk was used to seal the gap.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider extending the backsplash forward along the cabinet, if there is one -- or adding one if there isn't. It still leaves you with countertop material abutting wood, but it would at least look more deliberate and be more spill resistant.

Comment: Extending the backsplash - then you have two joints that might require caulking (where the backsplash meets the cabinet, and where the backsplash meets the counter.

Comment: Granted. On the other hand, you have an easier surface to clean at that junction than wood. Just offering it as an option.

Comment: @SteveSh assuming the cabinet wall is straight, the backsplash will be a lot neater a line than the slightly uneven countertop that's there now.